# any way remove history commit but keep all file 1 log?

Tags: git

I have a git repo with a same file has many log

```
df5bf4b a.file
c1f6f9f a.file
4e818fa b.file
f954acf b.file
```

I wanna remove old logs but keep at last one commit log on each files

for reduce git repo size

how can i do this?

```
df5bf4b a.file
4e818fa b.file
```

Comment: ***Why*** do you want to do this?

Comment: @Makoto log is from my bad auto test commit, and each file is about 1~3mb with total 700+ logs

Comment: So this is more about removing binaries from your history more than anything else?

Comment: @Makoto https://gitee.com/demogitee/epub-txt/commits/master

Comment: That's asking me to log in, and is not entirely germane to the question I posed to you.

Comment: @Makoto i think is yes, i wanna delete  binaries old log, but keep each  binaries with last one commit

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you do not have any other files in your repository that you want to keep other versions of, you can do this by deleting the git repository, initializing a new one, then making a commit. Something like this:

```
cd your_project_root_directory/
rm -rf .git/
git init
git add *.file
git commit -m "Add files"
```

Comment: given how strange OP's request is, this is a very reasonable course of action.